# Parse.com - Cloud code - Java Support?

Tags: parse-platform

Does Parse.com' Cloud code support Java in addition to Java Script ?
Is there any other parse.com component that will support Java ? 
I'm working on a mobile app that needs heavy server side data processing, so I'm wondering whether the java script SDK from Parse.com is flexible enough. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

They provide a client SDK for your Java (I'm guessing Android?) mobile client.

All server-side code uses the JavaScript API, with access to a few extra things in `Parse.Cloud` that only work server-side.

Each can use their own SDK/API without issues, as they all use REST under the covers and talk to the same central database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any language on another server, sending data by httprequests and receiving data via parse webhooks. That also is a way to work around parse's time limit for cloud code functions.

Check the link http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-cloud-code-webhooks/